# $m+n\sqrt{2}$ is a dense in R. Another approach

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In order to prove, that $m+n\sqrt{2}$ is a dense, can we just argue(and prove), that between a pair of real numbers always exists the rational number. If so, we can show that there are infinitely many limit points in set $m+n\sqrt{2}$.

Because i can't understand, why do we need to show, that $(\sqrt2-1)^n\to 0 $ How will it help?

Comment: Are $m,n$ integers? Presumably, you need $(\sqrt{2}-1)^n\to 0$, not $\to \infty$, because $\to\infty$ is false...

Comment: What does the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$ have to do with the density of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, of course $o$. and yes, $m,n$ are integers.
How does this sequence will help us in proof?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen because $m+n\sqrt{2}$ is real number. But I think, that my logic is wrong now...

Comment: @Dan_yef Try expanding $(\sqrt 2 -1)^n$. It is of the form $M+N\sqrt 2$ for some integers $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Given a real number $\epsilon>0$, then for every real number $x$ has an integer $m$ so that $|m\epsilon-x|<\epsilon$. Us this with $\epsilon=(\sqrt 2-1)^n$ and then you see why you need the limit.

Comment: The set of numbers of the form $m+n\sqrt{2}$ for integer $m,n$ is closed under addition and multiplication, and (as shown by this limit) can take arbitrarily small positive and negative values, so any interval contains examples of these numbers.

Comment: @Henry I took the limit and found, that  set $m+n\sqrt{2}$ takes small value iff $-m = n$. But this is only "small" part of the whole set.
What about the whole set? Sorry, for such questions, but I really can't understand it..

Answer (score 1):

For two numbers $a, b$ in this set note that the convex combination $(\sqrt{2}-1)a+(2-\sqrt{2})b$ is also in the set.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that $(\sqrt2-1)^n$ is an element of $H=\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z\sqrt{2}=\{ m+n\sqrt{2}\; |\; m,n\in\mathbb Z\; \}$ (it is easy to see it using the Binomial Theorem) and the following theorem:

> Let $(G,+)$ be a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$. Then one of the following must be true:
>
> 1. Either $G$ is cyclic: there exists $a$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $G=<a>=\mathbb Za$.
> 2. Either $G$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

The idea of the proof is to consider $a=\inf\{x \in G\; |\; x>0  \}$. If $a>0$, then $G=<a>$ and if $a=0$, then $G$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

In the case of $H=\mathbb Z+\mathbb Z\sqrt{2}$, $x_n=(\sqrt2-1)^n$ is a sequence of positive elements of $H$ whose limit is $0$ so $\inf\{x \in H\; |\; x>0  \}=0$. The theorem implies that $H$ is dense.